# Python Package ImportError in Windows

Tags: python, windows, importerror, tabular

I am having difficulty installing Python Packages on Windows. Following all of the responses to questions on this website and others I found through Google didn't solve the problem.

I originally followed this guide:
http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/starting/install/win/

I've tried re-installing Python, updating pip and the rest of the install packages, installing manually with python install tabular, updating the registry, and installing a fresh copy of Python in a clean VM.

Thanks for your help in advance!

This is the output from pip:

```
>  Running setup.py egg_info for package tabular
> 
>     Traceback (most recent call last):
> 
>       File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
> 
>       File "c:\users\jgerber\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_jgerber\tabular\setup.py",
> line 50, in <module>
> 
>         raise ImportError("distribute was not found and fallback to setuptools was not allowed")
> 
>     ImportError: distribute was not found and fallback to setuptools was not allowed
> 
>     Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
> 
>     Traceback (most recent call last):
> 
>   File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
> 
>   File
> "c:\users\jgerber\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_jgerber\tabular\setup.py",
> line 50, in <module>
> 
>     raise ImportError("distribute was not found and fallback to setuptools was not allowed")
> 
> ImportError: distribute was not found and fallback to setuptools was
> not allowed
> 
> ----------------------------------------
> 
> Cleaning up...
> 
>   Removing temporary dir
> c:\users\jgerber\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_jgerber... Command
> python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in
> c:\users\jgerber\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_jgerber\tabular
> 
> Exception information: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 134, in main
>     status = self.run(options, args)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 236, in
> run
>     requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)   File
> "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 1134, in
> prepare_files
>     req_to_install.run_egg_info()   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 259, in run_egg_info
>     command_desc='python setup.py egg_info')   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\util.py", line 670, in
> call_subprocess
>     % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd)) InstallationError: Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in
> c:\users\jgerber\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_jgerber\tabular
```

Comment: The error message suggests `distribute` is not found.  Is `distribute` installed?  What do you get if you do `pip install distribute`?

Comment: I had already tried that, but I ran it again. "pip list" shows distribute (0.7.3) as being installed.

Comment: This error continues even after installing/updating distribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue with tabular on windows. By including
http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py
in the same folder as the setup.py file, it installed without issues.

Comment: The python-distribute.org is now a parked domain. I don't think it's authoritative, but you can get distribute_setup.py here: https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/oodt/tools/oodtsite.publisher/trunk/distribute_setup.py

By the way, the first time I went to python-distribute.org, it tried to make me download malware. So definitely avoid that site.

Answer (score 1):

pip can't find distribute

run `pip install distribute`

or if pip's path is not set run `c:\python27\Scripts\pip.exe distribute`

---

you can similarly try `easy_install distribute`

or `c:\python27\Scripts\easy_install.exe distribute`

Comment: I had already tried that, but I ran it again. "pip list" shows distribute (0.7.3) as being installed.

Comment: This error continues even after installing/updating distribute.

Comment: what are you trying to install? Or is the error for every pip install?

Comment: I am trying to install the tabular package. The error seems to be for only some pip installs.